# Cómo Exportar un Excel por medio de una vista

Tags: laravel, excel

Como puedo exportar un archivo por medio de una vista, dicha vista es dinámica, esa vista realiza filtros para hacer búsqueda de la base de datos

Comment: Normalmente no se exporta a excel una vista mas bien se exporta los datos que se muestran en esa vista, de esa manera puedes aplicar los filtros y el resultado de esa consulta que normalmente pasas a tu view, se lo pasarias a tu excel

Comment: Antemano Muchas gracias por responder, si mi vista son dinámicas, tengo un vista donde realiza los filtros, pero en esa vista solo muestro ciertas columnas pero al momento de descargar el excel, utilizaría otra vista dónde tengo las columnas que necesito mostras.